# how to embed link youtube to be dynamic in codeigniter

Tags: php, youtube, codeigniter-3, embed

I want to display the youtube link stored in the database and just call the link but it can't

```
    <div class="divideo">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $link; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

but youtube can't connect

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is `$link;`?

Comment: please show your Youtube link.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="divideo">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/path/<?php echo $link ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
```

You should have to give the proper path of the video link if that link is in your server if you are using an external source then use a proper link in your src tag.